# What's the most efficient way to earn credits in Puyo Puyo Tetris (ぷよぷよテトリス)?

Tags: puyo-puyo-tetris

In *Puyo Puyo Tetris* (*ぷよぷよテトリス*) playing games in the various modes earns you credits.  These credits can then be used to unlock things like skins and characters.  However, after playing for 5-ish hours (mostly single-player Adventure, and a mix of the multiplayer modes), I barely have 2000 credits earned.  This is nowhere near enough to unlock everything, it's roughly enough to unlock a character or two.  I'd like to do this more efficiently, just so everything's available.

What's the most time efficient way to earn credits in *Puyo Puyo Tetris*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is paraphrased from [***Sonic Angel Knight's guide to unlocking content quickly in Puyo Puyo Tetris***](https://gbatemp.net/threads/simple-guide-to-unlocking-content-quickly-in-puyo-puyo-tetris.497444/). (Refer to the linked guide for more detailed info)

---

If you want to skip grinding for credits, you can unlock everything in the game with a cheat code. (This includes content unlocked from Adventure Mode)

#### Method 1 - Cheat Code

To permanently unlock all characters, skins, voice packs, and music, enter the following cheat code on the title screen. (A jingle will play if done correctly)

- **Switch/Wii U/3DS**: Hold L and R, then press Up, Down, Right, Left, X, B, Y, Y.
- **PS4/PS3**: Hold L1 and R1, press Up, Down, Right, Left, Triangle, Circle, Square, Square.
- **Xbox One/PC***: Hold LB and RB then press Up, Down, Right, Left, Y, B, X, X.

  <sup>*Assumes you are using an Xbox controller for PC.</sup>

#### Method 2 - Grinding Credits

If want to grind out credits instead, you can use the following exploit:

> 1. Go to the arcade mode and select Big Bang Mode > Battle > One CPU
> 2. On the character select screen, press start to skip it. (It auto selects current highlighted characters for all)
> 3. You should be on the custom options screen, this is the screen where you set up how you will play the mode. Simply hold both shoulder
>      buttons (L1/RB/R & R1/RB/R) and select play.
> 4. Notice how you don't have control over your chosen character, it should be playing by itself at a very intense rate while the opponent
>      is very tame. Simply wait for the battle to be over and see see the
>      results. (Your character will always win which is what you want)
> 5. On the results screen, you should notice you earned credits based on performance. Baseline, Chains, and all clears will total how much
>      credits you earn, because of the performance being random, this will
>      fluctuate. You can simply hit retry and watch it all over again.
> 6. After some time pass doing this method, you should have accumulated a lot in a short time. Please remember the maximum credits you can
>      hold at once is 9999, so make sure to spend them before repeating the
>      method again to get more. (You should need at least 3 trips to the
>      store at max credit score.